# How do I use a countdown thread properly, how do I stop it prematurely?

Tags: python, multithreading

Threading is not working the way I expect it.

I have a working solution where I monitor when a fridge gets opened and closed with a Raspberry Pi and a reed switch (playback of a sound is unpaused and paused). I now wanted to add a timer to do something when the door is kept open too long. I figured starting a thread which would sleep for x seconds before the alerting action would be a good idea. I would kill the thread with a signal when the switch is closed again.

My approach is failing. The CountDown run thread is started but the terminate signal command is executed but has no effect. Additionally, the commands following `c.terminate()` are not executed. I looked at examples for threading but they seem to be for more complex situations. What am I missing?

The code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

import threading, subprocess, sys, time, syslog
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

sound = "/home/pi/sounds/fridge_link.mp3" # sound to play while switch is open
cmd = ['mplayer', '-nolirc', '-noconsolecontrols', '-slave', '-quiet', sound] # command to play sound
lim = 10 # seconds until warning

# thread for countdown (should be interruptable)
# based on http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000393/ch12.html#_solution_197
class CountdownTask:
    def __init__(self):
        self._running = True

    def terminate(self):
        self._running = False
        print("thread killed")

    def run(self, n):
        print("start timer")
        time.sleep(n)
        ## action when timer isup 
        print("timer ended")


c = CountdownTask()
t = threading.Thread(target=c.run, args=(lim,))
t.daemon = True

p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
p.stdin.write('\npausing_keep pause\n')

REED = 27 # data pin of reed sensor (in)

# GPIO setup
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(REED,GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

def edge(channel):
    if GPIO.input(REED):
        print("detect close")
        c.terminate()
        p.stdin.write('\npause\n')
        pass
    else:
        print("detect open")
        t.start()
    p.stdin.write('\npausing_toggle pause\n')

def main():
    GPIO.add_event_detect(REED, GPIO.BOTH,callback=edge,bouncetime=1000)
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.2)
        pass

#------------------------------------------------------------

if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

New version:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

import threading, subprocess, sys, time, syslog
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

sound = "/home/pi/sounds/fridge_link.mp3" # sound to play while switch is open
cmd = ['mplayer', '-nolirc', '-noconsolecontrols', '-slave', '-quiet', sound] # command to play sound
lim = 10 # seconds until warning

# thread for countdown (should be interruptable)
class CountdownTask:
    global dooropen
    def __init__(self):
        self._running = True

    def terminate(self):
        self._running = False
        print("thread killed")

    def run(self, n):
      while self._running and dooropen == False:
          time.sleep(0.2)
          pass
      while self._running and dooropen:
        print("start timer")
        time.sleep(n)
        ## action when timer isup 
        print("timer ended")


c = CountdownTask()
t = threading.Thread(target=c.run, args=(lim,))
t.daemon = True

p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
p.stdin.write('\npausing_keep pause\n')

REED = 27 # data pin of reed sensor (in)

# GPIO setup
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(REED,GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

dooropen = False # assuming door's closed when starting


def edge(channel):
    global dooropen
    if GPIO.input(REED): # * no longer reached
        if dooropen == False: # catch fridge compressor spike
            print("false close alert") 
            return
        p.stdin.write('\npause\n') 
        dooropen = False
        pass
    else:
        print("detect open")
        if dooropen == True:
            print("false open alert")
            return        
    p.stdin.write('\npausing_toggle pause\n')
    dooropen = True

def main():
    GPIO.add_event_detect(REED, GPIO.BOTH,callback=edge,bouncetime=1000)
    t.start()
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.2)
        pass

#------------------------------------------------------------

if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

Adjusted section, working now:

```
    def run(self, n):
      while self._running and dooropen == False:
          time.sleep(0.2)
          pass
      while self._running and dooropen:
        time.sleep(n)
        if dooropen:
            ## action when timer isup
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your programmed thread termination mechanism via `self._running` is not working, because you are not polling/checking the state of `self._running` in the `run()` method of the tread (that is actually done in the example you were referring to).

Regular polling adds complexity that is not necessary here. You should structure your logic in a different way, which is simple and reliable. Example code:

```
import threading
import time


dooropen = True


def warnafter(timeout):
    time.sleep(timeout)
    if dooropen:
        print("Warning!")


t = threading.Thread(target=warnafter, args=(2,))
t.start()
time.sleep(1)
dooropen = False
t.join()
```

Change `time.sleep(1)` to `time.sleep(3)` and a warning is printed. Why does this work, and how does this translate to your use case?

First of all, let's give things names. You have your main thread and the "warn thread". These are the cornerstones of the architecture in my example code:

- Have a shared state between the two threads indicating whether the door is open or not, translating into the fact whether a warning should be issued or not. Let's call this state `dooropen`, and it can be `True` or `False`. It is a variable accessible in both, the scope of your main thread as well as in the scope your warn thread has access to. That is, it lives in shared memory.
- This is your convention: `dooropen` is only written from the main thread. The warn thread only reads it.
- Spawn your warn thread whenever you think it is the right time. Make it sleep (the exact sleep time can be unreliable, especially on embedded systems).
- The crucial part: right before raising an alarm in the warn thread, make it check the `dooropen` state. If `not dooropen`, simply do not raise the alarm!

Do you see the two different paradigms?

Your paradigm is to plant an armed bomb, programmed to explode after a given amount of time. This bomb does not talk back to you anymore. Your hope is that you are able to defuse/*destroy* the bomb before it can explode, if you do not need it to explode anymore.

The paradigm I am proposing ships a bomb that actually is not armed until it needs to be. At the point in time when your bomb would simply explode, this one **asks** if it really should do so, and only then arms itself and explodes.

Given the latter paradigm, if the warn thread is told to not perform its action, it *silently* quits, on its own. The concept of "terminating the thread from the outside" is not needed!

In practice, you would need a little more advanced concept, where a warn thread has *its own* `active` switch. That is, your main thread can deactivate single warn threads in a controlled fashion. See this example:

```
import threading
import time


class WarnThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, timeout, name):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self._timeout = timeout
        self.active = True
        self.name = name
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        self._warnafter()

    def _warnafter(self):
        time.sleep(self._timeout)
        if self.active:
            print("WarnThread %s: Warning after timeout" % self.name)


ws = [WarnThread(2, i) for i in range(5)]

# Simulate spending some time doing other things,
# such as responding to external events.
time.sleep(1)

# Selectively deactivate some of the warn threads.
ws[0].active = False
ws[2].active = False

for w in ws:
    w.join()
```

Output:

```
WarnThread 4: Warning after timeout
WarnThread 1: Warning after timeout
WarnThread 3: Warning after timeout
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. My actual script has a door state variable, I use it to catch false alarms (triggered by power spikes from the fridge's compressor). I left it out to not cause confusion. I added it again and, I think, I followed your suggestions. Yet, somehow, the door closed branch in the edge function isn't reached anymore, the dooropen variable doesn't get set to False and the timer keeps looping.

I added the updated script.

Comment: You did not resolve the core issue, you are still calling `## action when timer isup` **right after** doing `time.sleep(n)`. That is, there is no check for `self._running` after doing the sleep. Your warn thread is **not responsive** to external status updates.

Comment: I now added an `if dooropen` check after the sleep as suggested. Tt is working now, thank you! Also, there were some indent errors that caused the door close part of the edge function to never be reached.