# Countdown thread RPi stop if GPIO input change

Tags: python, linux, raspbian, python-multithreading, gpio

I'm not sure the best way to do this, and is not working for my as it will lock the program on when its asleep not sure how to make it works right...

Im trying to monitor when a door open and closes with a raspberry Pi if there door is open for more than x time send some sort of alert (like and email), I've the problem that when the door closes before the countdown finished it wont stop the countdown, which causes the thread to halt, also havent implemented the alert side of thing but if the code is as at the moment it will trigger the alert even if the door closes before countdown.

At the moment I'm using a push button instead of a door sensor for testing, , also eventually i will log the opening and closing of the door, but for now id like to know if there is a nicer way of doing this, i got the code im using from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28459996/how-do-i-use-a-countdown-thread-properly-how-do-i-stop-it-prematurely)

my code is as follows

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import threading, subprocess, sys, time, syslog
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

lim = 2 # seconds until warning

# thread for countdown (should be interruptable)
class CountdownTask:
    global dooropen
    global countdone

    def __init__(self):
        #print("thread in")
        self._running = True

    def start(self):
        print("thread in")
        self._running = True

    def terminate(self):
        print("thread killed")
        self._running = False

    def run(self, n):
        while True:
            global countdone

            while self._running and dooropen == False and countdone:
                pass

            while self._running and dooropen == False and countdone == False:
                pass

            while self._running and dooropen and countdone:
                pass

            while self._running and dooropen and countdone == False:
                print("start timer")
                time.sleep(5)
                if dooropen:
                    ## action when timer isup
                    print("timer ended, send notify")
                    countdone = True


c = CountdownTask()
t = threading.Thread(target=c.run, args=(lim,))
t.daemon = True

REED = 23 # data pin of reed sensor (in)

# GPIO setup
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(REED, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

dooropen = False # assuming door's closed when starting
countdone = True


def edge(channel):
    global dooropen
    global countdone

    if GPIO.input(REED): # * no longer reached
        if dooropen == False: # catch fridge compressor spike
            print("Detect open")
            countdone = False
            dooropen = True
        else:
            print("Door closed")
            dooropen = False

def main():
    GPIO.add_event_detect(REED, GPIO.RISING, callback=edge, bouncetime=300)
    t.start()
    while True:
        pass

#------------------------------------------------------------

if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

**Update:**

Looks like I need to be using threading.Event and wait could someone advise how to implement this on my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i got a working script

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import threading
import time
import logging
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import smtplib
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,format='(%(threadName)-9s) %(message)s',)

# GPIO setup
Input = 23 # data pin of Input sensor (in)

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(Input, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

global button
button = False
global count
count = 1
#global t
t = 1
countdown = 5

def sendmail():
    fromaddr = "email"
    toaddr = "tomail"
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = fromaddr
    msg['To'] = toaddr
    msg['Subject'] = "DoorAlarm"

    body = "This is a test mail generated with python on a RPi"
    msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login("username", "password")
    text = msg.as_string()
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
    server.quit()


def timeout(e, t):
    global count
    global button

    while True:
        while button:
            while not e.isSet() and count <= countdown:
                if count == 1: logging.debug('starting counter')
                event_is_set = e.wait(t)
                if event_is_set:
                    count = 1
                    logging.debug('Door closed before countdown')
                else:
                    count += 1
                if count == countdown:
                    logging.debug('countdown completed - notify')
                    #sendmail()

def edge(channel):
    global button
    global count

    if button == False: # catch fridge compressor spike
        button = True
        e.clear()
        print("log door open")
        if count != 1:
            count = 1

    else:
        button = False
        e.set()
        print("log door closed")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    e = threading.Event()

    t = threading.Thread(name='non-blocking',target=timeout,args=(e, t))
    t.start()

    logging.debug('Waiting before calling Event.set()')
    GPIO.add_event_detect(Input, GPIO.RISING, callback=edge, bouncetime=300)
```